# Logo at right of title on first page

Tags: titling

I want to  place a logo to the right of the title information on the first page of a document, like this:

[image]

My current code looks like this:

```
\usepackage{titling}
\pretitle{\begin{center}\LARGE\includegraphics[width=4cm]{../goanna/www/goanna.jpg}\\[\bigskipamount]}
\posttitle{\end{center}}
```

and displays the logo above and central:

[image]

How do I modify the code to get the required result, including the program version number below the logo?

Thanks in advance for any response.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please provide a [compilable document](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), not just a fragment.

Answer (score 3):

Not so neat nor clean but can work. Someone definately could improve it.

- I replicated the date displaying with `yyyymmdd` of `datetime`
  package.
- Note that one can use a *false* caption below a picture with
  `\stackunder` of `stackengine` package.
- `\documentclass[a5paper]{article}` and `\usepackage[top=1cm]{geometry}` were used to preplicate the visualization of first image, you can remove paper size and geometry package if necessary.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{stackengine} % For \stackunder command
\usepackage[yyyymmdd]{datetime}
\renewcommand{\dateseparator}{--}

%\usepackage{titling}
%\pretitle{\begin{center}\LARGE\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}\\[\bigskipamount]}
%\posttitle{\par\end{center}}

\begin{document}

\hspace{-4ex}
\begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth}{%
    \fontsize{22pt}{10pt}
    \selectfont\textbf{Title}}\\[2mm]
    \Large\textsc{\textit{JF}}\\[2mm]
    \normalsize{\today}\\
    \hrule
\end{minipage}\hfill
    \stackunder[5pt]{%
    \raisebox{-5mm}{\includegraphics[scale=.1]{goanna.jpg}}}{Goanna 1.0}
    \vspace{5mm}

\section*{Loren Ipsum}
\noindent
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hmmm, you did not specify it was to integrate it in RMarkdown. I am not sure it can work though. I hope it works.